# How to replace the samples in a 3d array in python?

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I have a 3d array of dimension (1000, 300, 3), my_3d_array.

I want to modify each sample if this array then replace the old version with the modified one. In another word, I want to take the 1st example (300, 3) (lets called it old sample) apply some modification to it by calling a function called my_function, then the obtained new one will replace the old sample in my_3d_array, and so on.
How can we do it please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not exactly sure this is what you want, but you can use the normal indexing notation:

```py
# just an example array
my_3d_array = np.random.random((1000,300,3))

# extract the old sample
old_sample = my_3d_array[0,:,:]

# transform the sample
new_sample = my_function(old_sample)

# write the sample back to the original array
my_3d_array[0,:,:] = new_sample
```

If you want to do the same transformation for all samples it might be beneficial to vectorize `my_function` to process all samples at once instead of using a python loop.

Comment: In general, this is the solution I'm looking for.It works for one sample. but I am looking if i can apply my function to all the 1000 samples one shot.

Comment: Is using a `for` loop over the first dimension of the array not an option?

Comment: using a loop will be inefficient since my_3d_array can be a huge array.

Comment: There are helper functions in numpy, e.g. `apply_along_axis` and `vectorize` https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/routines.functional.html. These could be used, but i doubt that they will give a significant performance boost because they also have to call your python function as many times as there are samples in your array. If  `my_function` only uses numpy functions you can try to vectorize the function directly, this would probably give the best performance.

Comment: my_function uses np.random.normal(loc=0, scale=scale_value, size=sample.shape), and some times it uses np.matmul(). So I think vectorizing my_function is the best solution